# Summarizing successive polygons areas?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I have a shape with 110 polygons (hydrographic basins in certain computational sections).  I have to sum up their surfaces from upstream to downstream. below is an example of polygons representation. for example, sum for polygon 2 is  surface 1 + surface 2, for polygon 4 is surface 1 + surface 2 + surface 3 + surface 4.... and so on.

Is there any Python script or a ModelBuilder to automatically determine the surface for all polygons in the computational sections?

[image]

Comment: I only tried in excel with autosum. but I don't want to do this for 110 polygons. I just want to know if is possible to do this in arcgis. thanks.

Comment: I would do it using an ArcPy update cursor but it should be possible but clumsier to do with ModelBuilder too.

Comment: If you are only comfortable doing it in Excel you could just join the result from that (converted into a table) with your feature class.